# How properly to bundle an aurelia plugin that html files, js files, and dependencies?

Tags: gulp, aurelia, jspm

## Situation

We are using a [fork of benib/aurelia-leaflet](https://github.com/shaunluttin/aurelia-leaflet) in our app.

```
jspm install github:shaunluttin/aurelia-leaflet
```

The plugin [includes the original in its installation as a dependency](https://github.com/shaunluttin/aurelia-leaflet/blob/master/package.json#L44-L46) and results in the following installation.

```
jspm_packages
  github
    Leaflet              <----- the original
      Leaflet@0.7.7
        dist 
          images
          leaftlet.css
          leaflet.js
          leaflet-src.js      <----- dependency
      Leaflet@0.7.7.js
    shaunluttin
      aurelia-leftlet@0.1.2       <----- the aurelia plugin
        helpers
        aurelia-leaflet-exceptions.js
        index.js                         <----- dependency
        leaflet.html
        leaflet.js
        leaflet-defaults.js
      aurelia-leaflet@0.1.2.js
```

These are the module definitions pointing to the dependencies.

Leaflet@0.7.7.js

```
define(["github:Leaflet/Leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet-src"], function(main) {
  return main;
});
```

aurelia-leaflet@0.1.2.js

```
define(["github:shaunluttin/aurelia-leaflet@0.1.2/index"], function(main) {
  return main;
});
```

To improve performance, we're bundling aurelia-leaflet like this:

```
"dist/leaflet-bundle":
  "includes": [
    "shaunluttin/aurelia-leaflet",        
    "shaunluttin/aurelia-leaflet/*.js",
    "shaunluttin/aurelia-leaflet/leaflet.html!text"
    ],
```

`gulp bundle` uses the aurelia-bundler to create the following bundle.

```
"leaflet-bundle.js" : [
  "github:Leaflet/Leaflet@0.7.7.js",
  "github:Leaflet/Leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet-src.js",
  "github:shaunluttin/aurelia-leaflet@0.1.2.js",
  "github:shaunluttin/aurelia-leaflet@0.1.2/aurelia-leaflet-exceptions.js",
  "github:shaunluttin/aurelia-leaflet@0.1.2/helpers/layer-factory.js",
  "github:shaunluttin/aurelia-leaflet@0.1.2/index.js",
  "github:shaunluttin/aurelia-leaflet@0.1.2/leaflet-defaults.js",
  "github:shaunluttin/aurelia-leaflet@0.1.2/leaflet.html!github:systemjs/plugin-text@0.0.3.js",
  "github:shaunluttin/aurelia-leaflet@0.1.2/leaflet.js"
]
```

The bundling includes the original leaftlet because aurelia-leaflet specifies the dependency in its index.js file.

## Question

Is there a way to do the bundling of aurelia-leaflet without having to specify each file type? This seems verbose:

```
"dist/leaflet-bundle":
  "includes": [
    "shaunluttin/aurelia-leaflet",        
    "shaunluttin/aurelia-leaflet/*.js",
    "shaunluttin/aurelia-leaflet/leaflet.html!text"
    ],
```